# Библиотеки для создания диаграмм и графиков Canvas  и SVG

Tags: svg, canvas, javascript

Какие `JavaScript` библиотеки Вы используете для создания диаграмм и графиков в своих веб-приложениях? Интересуют библиотеки, которые работают как с `Canvas`, так и с `SVG`. И еще - интересуют только бесплатные библиотеки...

Comment: Их очень много, выбирайте любую "javascript chart library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[D3JS](http://d3js.org/), [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)